# Set different display rule for nested list

Tags: css

(Hopefully) quick question:

I have an unordered list set to display:table and li set to display:table cell, as I want the list to take up entire width of container div regardless of how many list items there are. The problem is I want a nested drop-down list to have a block display, so the items are under each other. I've done the drop-down before by setting parent list to Block, floating left, then setting the nested list to float:none.

I've tried a few things to set the nested list from table to block, but it's not doing it for me!

And I missing something simple, or is this going to work the way I want?

Here's the HTML

```
<div id = "headernavcontainer">

            <div id = "headernav">

                <ul id = "mainnav">

                    <li><a class = "mainnav" href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                    <li><a class = "mainnav" href="#">Company</a>

                        <ul>

                            <li><a class = "subnav" href="index.html">About Us</a></li> 
                            <li><a class = "subnav" href="#">Location</a></li>
                            <li><a class = "subnav" href="#">Services</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li><a class = "mainnav" href="#">Employment</a></li>
                    <li><a class = "mainnav" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a class = "mainnav" href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#headernavcontainer
{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#headernav
{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:960px;
    background-color:gray;

}

#mainnav
{
    list-style:none;
    //float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    display:table;
    font-family:Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: .8em;
}

#mainnav li

{
    //float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    line-height:50px;
    margin-right:0;
    display:table-cell;
    border-right:1px #000 solid;
}

#mainnav li:nth-child(10)
{
    border-right:none;
}

#mainnav a.mainnav
{
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    //vertical-align:middle;
}

#mainnav a:hover
{
    color:#fff;
    background:red;
}

#mainnav ul
{
    display:block   !important;
    //overflow:hidden;
    background:#fff;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    //vertical-align:middle;
    background:green;
}

#mainanv ul li
{
    //float:none;
    //display:block;
    display:block   !important;
}

#mainnav li:hover ul
{
    left:0;
    //display:block;
}
```

And here's a jfiddle to help illustrate what I'm up to! http://jsfiddle.net/cEw5k/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cEw5k/1/

CSS:

```
#mainnav li:hover ul
{  
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    padding-left:0;
}

#mainnav li ul li {
    display:block;
}

#mainnav li ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:95%;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: That's it! So I basically needed to continue and add display:block to the other elements in the nested list. Excellent, thanks!

Comment: One strange issue regarding this overall code, making the nested ul width:100% makes the nested list item 100% the width of the list item that contains it in Chrome, however, in Firefox it makes the nested drop-down list 100% the width of the entire parent list. Something is being ignored by Firefox. Tried changing to width:auto, but this causes the drop-down to stick to the very right of the parent list regardless of what list item it is nested in.

Comment: I fixed it, you look at http://jsfiddle.net/cEw5k/2/

Before it error because Firefox doesn’t support a combination of display:table-cell and position:relative. You need add a <div> cover <a> and <ul> subitem